# TCL Regular Expression Doubt

Tags: regex, tcl

As per my understanding of RE

--> `*` means matches 0 or more occurrences of prev regex
--> `+` means matches 1 or more occurrences of prev regex

Now lets take a look at the following examples

FIRST:-

```
% regexp {:+} "DHCP:Enabled" first
1
% puts $first
:                     --> ":" is stored in variable first
%
```

SECOND:-

```
% regexp {:*} "DHCP:Enabled" sec
1
% puts $sec
                     --> Nothing is stored in variable second
%
```

Why is ":" stored for the FIRST one and not the SECOND?

Answer (score 7):

The second regexp `{:*}` matches the empty string because the empty string is 0 occurrences of `:`.  If you use the `-indices` option for `regexp`, you'll see that it matches at position 0.

```
 % regexp -indices :* "DHCP:Enabled" indices
 1
 % puts $indices
 0 -1
```

In other words, the regexp matches at the first character and returns.

Answer (score 0):

It matches the empty string so that it can
match that empty string at the start of “`DHCP:Enabled`”. The regular
expression engine like to match things up as soon as possible. To show, here's an interactive session:

```
% regexp -inline {:*} "DHCP:Enabled"
{}
% regexp -inline -all {:*} "DHCP:Enabled"
{} {} {} {} : {} {} {} {} {} {} {}
% regexp -inline -indices -all {:*} "DHCP:Enabled"
{0 -1} {1 0} {2 1} {3 2} {4 4} {5 4} {6 5} {7 6} {8 7} {9 8} {10 9} {11 10}
```

The `-inline` option is useful for simple testing, the `-all` matches in
every matchable location instead of just the first, and the `-indices`
returns locations rather than the string.

Note that only once (`4 4`) is the end at least at the same index as the start; in all other cases, an empty string matches (and it's legal; you said that matching nothing was OK).

In general, it's a really good idea to **make sure that your overall RE cannot match the empty string** or you'll be surprised by the results.